# jQuery Date Picker Min Max date issue

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<?php
$week_start_date = '2012-02-06';
$week_start_date = '2012-02-12';
?>

$("#test").datepicker({
    altField: "#test1",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    autoSize: true,
    minDate: new Date("<?php echo $week_start_date; ?>"),
    maxDate: new Date("<?php echo $week_end_date; ?>")
});
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

In my location(**India**) the range restriction seems display right. but in **US** the range shows from 2012-02-05 to 2012-02-11.

I dont know why its making restriction on day prior. i checked in the firebug the restriction range is right but in **US** the range is displaying as **2012-02-05 to 2012-02-11**.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Timezone issue? Pushing to the timezone in the US from your time might be causing the days to jump one back? :/

Comment: yes. how to solve this. i need universally to display the range in a right way

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754740/jquery-datepicker-formatdate-and-timezone-offset), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138208/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-timezones), or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398931/jquery-date-picker-timezone-issue)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the same script is getting executed in two different places. Note that these script will be running at the user's browser, which make use of user timezone.

When you run `minDate: new Date("2012-02-12")`, the passed parameter used to calculate Date in local timezone. So if you are in `IST`, it will generate date for `2012-02-12, 50:30` and if you are in `EST`, it will generate `2012-02-11, 19:00`.

Solution, generate Date object by full date and time values,

```
> d = new Date(2012,02,12,00,00,00)
=> Date {Mon Mar 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

Comment: I had gn start date as new Date(2012,01,30,00,00,00); and end date as new Date(2012,02,5,23,59,59);

Comment: In javascript month starts with 0, Jan is represented as 0, feb as 1 and so on. So with above date you are trying to create 30th Feb 2012, which doesn't exist and hence pointing to 1st March 2012. Try `new Date(2012,00,20,00,00,00)`